Why would a selfish intention/action be superior to a selfless one?
In this comment it was pointed out as per AN 4:95 that one who practises solely for one’s benefits is better than one who practises solely for others’ benefits. While the best of the 4 types of individuals is those who practise for theirs and others’ benefits.
It seems strange that a selfless and altruistic intention is seen as lower and less refined than a selfish one by the Buddha. This answer proposed possible reasons why type 3 (solely for oneself) is better than type 2 (solely for others). In short, by practising for oneself, the individual indirectly confer protection to others as well as to oneself. But won’t the same effect be achieved with type 2? Is this right or is there something else?
By logical extension from the above, if one is practising for oneself and others there should be additional benefits as this type is the best of all according to the Buddha. Are there additional advantages and what are they?
The last question is somewhat related to an earlier post. If intentions are not to be judged on the basis of selfishness versus selflessness, what is the proper Buddhist criteria for deciding if an intention is noble/refine versus ignoble/base? Any insight is much appreciated.

The word "benefit" is given in a Buddhist context, which deals with the Four Noble Truths about suffering. We benefit by progressing along the path that leads to the end of suffering. Outside the Buddhist context, "benefit" can be crudely interpreted as "winning the lottery and going to Vegas". But the latter interpretation is disallowed by:

AN9.41:7.8: ‘I haven’t seen the drawbacks of sensual pleasures, and so I haven’t cultivated that. I haven’t realized the benefits of renunciation, and so I haven’t developed that.

So instead of talking about something like wealth as a benefit, let's take a better example to understand how the word "benefit" is used in Buddhism.
Now consider what we hear every time we fly on an airplane. When we fly, we are advised to put on our own oxygen masks before our children's oxygen masks. In other words, we secure the benefit of oxygen for ourselves, thereby ensuring that we can safely provide that same benefit to others.
The Buddha's own explanation does not rely on airplanes, but it does have the same sense:

AN4.95:4.1: From a cow comes milk, from milk comes curds, from curds come butter, from butter comes ghee, and from ghee comes cream of ghee. And the cream of ghee is said to be the best of these.
AN4.95:4.2: In the same way, the person who practices to benefit both themselves and others is the foremost, best, chief, highest, and finest of the four.

In the Buddha's explanation, "benefit" is compared to refining milk to progressively better quality, from milk to butter, ghee and beyond.  If someone can only make butter, that's really only what they can give to or teach others. The benefit is limited by the level of the person providing the benefit to others. It is not so hard to make butter (shake a container if milk for a long time). It is a bit harder to make ghee. And it takes a lot of mindful care to get the cream of the ghee without scorching it. All of these provide benefit, but to give better benefit, we have to be skilled in that benefit.
So "benefit" here is about the fruits of practice, the ending of suffering, and it is not about how much wealth or time we give to others.

The question appears to revolve around the meaning of "paṭipanno" (translated as "practises").
Without doing more research, my understanding is "paṭipanno" means to "proceed in the opposite direction", i.e,. from suffering to happiness. "Patipanno" is generally used for the Noble Eightfold Path.
I am not sure the first part/person of AN 4.95 is translated correctly. I guess it correctly means: "One who does not practice to benefit neither themselves nor others".
This aside, the other three persons are practising to end suffering or for "benefit" ("attha"). The first of these later three is practising to help others end suffering, such as being a preaching monk or a social worker (similar to a friend of mine who has a very good private business as a relationship counsellor but also has a problematic marriage).
Therefore, trying to help others when you cannot help yourself is obviously lesser than being able to help yourself.
Sorry for my brief answer but I must leave now to help myself on certain matters.

The inspiration for this answer came from an essay titled Honest to Goodness written by Venerable Thanissaro. In it was written:

Which intentions lead to suffering, and which to the end of suffering?

From the above, I think the yardstick or criteria used by the Buddha to determine if an intention or action is noble or ignoble is whether it eliminates overall suffering and for how long. With intentions and actions that lead to the end of suffering thus defined to be the most noble of all. This is quite different from the modern moral and ethical standards in society. We judged intentions/actions based on qualities such as altruism, tolerance, acceptance, humanity, universal love and so on. This had often resulted in confusing scenarios when the costs associated with such qualities grow exponentially and caused unintentional sufferings to others resulting in pushback by these disadvantaged groups. An example is the acceptance of refugees from other countries.
Initially, embracing and accepting refugees who are fleeing war, death, poverty and hunger seems like what a normal human would and should do. However, like all things in life, diminishing returns inevitably sets in (because resources are limited) and the country’s citizens find it increasingly difficult to host these refugees from a socioeconomic standpoint. Terms such as “economic refugees” began to appear and to be adopted by those opposed to such unconditional aid. This phenomenon similarly affected other areas such as diversity, equity, inclusion (DEI), wokeism, body positivity and so on. Pushbacks can be seen even in areas under the traditional purview of science such as vaccinations, genetically modified food and stem cells research/therapy. Perhaps, some would argue this is freedom of speech and expression. One should be at liberty to express, adopt and champion any ideals or values in a free and open society. However, the problem is without a universally acceptable criteria for determining what is good or bad, it is hard to decide what’s right or wrong at times.
Can this yardstick used by the Buddha be the universally acceptable criteria for deciding what is good or bad? I don’t know but I am quite certain it is the reason behind why the Buddha deemed selfish intention/action that led to an elimination of suffering to be superior to a selfless one that might unconsciously or unintentionally result in greater suffering. I will use an analogy of someone trying to become a cook in an attempt to better illustrate the 4 types of individuals in AN 4:95.
Type 3 would be a person who learned to cook by tasting and eating their own cooking. This person would learn quickly what is good and bad cooking, avoiding too much distress to themselves or to others. Type 2 would be someone who learned to cook by letting others taste and eat their cooking without personally trying out their own cooking. This person learns slowly from feedback from the tasters and causes much distress to themselves and others. Type 4 would be a person who tastes and eats their own food and also let others try out their cooking. This person learns fast like type 3. In addition, because they need to cater to the needs of others (preferences for spicy vs non-spicy, meat vs vegetables, oily vs non-oily and so on), they are better versed in a variety of culinary styles, ingredients and cooking techniques. All these allow type 4 to delight both themselves and others with their cooking.
Finally, type 1 would be someone who observe and try to emulate the cooking of others. Type 1 would neither actively taste or seek out others to try their cooking. Now and then, some random taster would show up and offer some feedback. (Note: as long as we exist, our presence would inevitably have an impact on others. If it impacts others negatively, they will provide strong feedback regardless). Obviously, this way of becoming a cook is slow, stressful and least effective of all.
Lastly, I believe this Buddhist criteria for determining noble or ignoble intentions/actions might help to better inform decisions not only at an individual level but also at the organizational, societal and even international level by evaluating if the overall suffering reduces or increases and whether the effect is sustainable and/or lasting. I agree it is not easy to implement but I think it is a more holistic approach that naturally has an implicit long-term consideration.
